# Binding database value to MaxLenght property

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, webforms

I have a table in a database:

```
ID  Name    MaxPlaces
1   Product  20
2   Group    30
3   AFG      40
```

I need to bind that MaxPlaces column to textbox in asp to MaxLenght property(MaxLength='<%# Bind("MaxPlaces") %>'):

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProduct" runat="server" Text="Product:"  Font-Names="Open Sans"></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtProduct" runat="server" Font-Names="Merriweather" margin-Left="100px"  AutoPostBack="true" MaxLength='<%# Bind("MaxPlaces") %>'></asp:TextBox><br />
                </td>

            </tr>
```

I have created a stored procedure:

```
@ID  nvarchar(100)

AS
BEGIN

      SELECT ID, Name, MaxPlaces
      FROM dbo.Level
      WHERE  ID = @ID;

END
```

That means MaxLenght property needs to have a value of '20' (First row from database)

I need C# code to set parameter value to '1' and send '20' to asp bind.

Can someone help me with this code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"to set parameter value to '1' "_, which parameter?

Comment: Parameter ID=1 in C# so MaxLength 20 could be sent to asp

Answer (score 0):

This is the code an explanation

```
public partial class DropDownExample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected int GetMaxLength(string passedValue)
    {
        //could check passedValue to determine length from database not shown

        //kudos https://forums.asp.net/t/1274891.aspx?Textbox+maxlength+using+variable
        return 10;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //you need this if you want to do it this way
        //you could just set the maxlength on control in codebehind
        txtProduct.DataBind();
    }
}
```

aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DropDownExample.aspx.cs" Inherits="FredWebForm.DropDownExample" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtProduct" runat="server" Font-Names="Merriweather" margin-Left="100px"
        AutoPostBack="true" MaxLength='<%# GetMaxLength("passedValue")%>'></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```